# Is my dev env should point to localhost API, or a public API on a dev subdomain?

Tags: node.js, git, deployment, development-environment

I want to make a good CI/CD pipeline. But I am not sure what are the keys of the best practice in here.

I have front end GUI's (Angular/React/etc) point to a backend API (build on Node.js and Express) and I wonder what is the best practice.

For example: when developing the Angular GUI, should I point to the localhost API or, point to a dev API which is public, like: `https://dev-api.example.ext` ? Should I run a DB on localhost, or that the DB should be a dev dedicated DB which is also hosts on the remote dev server?

When I move my Angular GUI (just for example) to staging, which should be a mirror of production, should it point to the real API url? or a staging API url? I think that it should point to the real one since in staging we should consider this as same as production.

Should I run GitHub hooks automatically to fire the build server to pull & build, or I should first review the merges and then do it manually?

I have tried to found a good article but found nothing.

Comment: Step back one step. What is the purpose that you are building this pipeline? Are you working alone on this project? What is your intention of building a pipeline to learn or something else?

Comment: @Raz you should use dev url for dev environment and staging url for staging environment not the production url, staging environment may be exact replica of production but the next release version which need to be tested before production. Also you can fire github hooks for dev automatically , but for other environment you should make review process. Also for databases generally every environment should point to there environment specific databases, not to localhost database or production database.

Comment: But if my GUI, on staging env, points to my staging-api.exmaple.ext and I want to test a real credit card transaction, I will get an error. Since real credit card transactions respects the api.exmaple.ext url, not the staging-api.exmaple.ext.
And also, maybe different servers for staging and production with different IP's or even different countries. There a chance that the credit card transaction company block one server but allow another. I cannot know this until the user will actually get blocked when he tries to pay. Got what I say?

Comment: @Raz you should not do the real data testing on staging you should emulate such functionalities on staging environment instead of using production one, you can align a preprod process or beta release for such testings.